# Closure compiler removing class namespaces

Tags: javascript, google-closure

I have a bunch of JavaScript prototypes inheriting from each other. Each class is defined in its own file like this. An example file looks like this:

```
goog.provide("app.classes.ClassA");

(function() {
    app.classes.ClassA = function() {
        // constructor
    }

    app.classes.ClassA.prototype.example = function() {
        // example method
    }

})();
```

A second file may look like this:

```
goog.provide("app.classes.ClassB");
goog.require("app.classes.ClassA");

(function() {
    app.classes.ClassB = function() {
        // constructor
    }

    goog.inherits(app.classes.ClassB, app.classes.ClassA);

    app.classes.ClassB.prototype.example = function() {
        // example method
    }

})();
```

After running the compiler, the code specified in the first file looks like this:

```
goog.provide("app.classes.ClassA");

(function() {
    a.classes.ClassA = function() {
        // constructor
    }

    a.classes.ClassA.prototype.example = function() {
        // example method
    }
})();
```

'app' in ClassA has been replaced by a single 'a' and goog.inherits cannot find app.classes.ClassA because it is undefined.

How can I prevent the Closure Compiler from renaming namespaces like this?

Thanks!

Comment: What you describe here is inconsistent with what I know about the compiler.  In SIMPLE mode "app" wouldn't be renamed. In ADVANCED, the properties would be.

How are you compiling your code?  Do you include extern definitions for any of this?  I assume that you are compiling the code separately rather than as a single compilation.

Comment: Why are you wrapping your namespace in a (function(){})()  You don't need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways, first you can annotate your external methods/variables/classes with @expose:

```
(function() {
    /**
    * @expose
    */
    a.classes.ClassA = function() {
        // constructor
    }

    a.classes.ClassA.prototype.example = function() {
        // example method
    }
})();
```

Or, you can disable optimizations when running the closure compiler:

```
java -jar ccompiler.jar --compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY ..
```